# php problem searching words in a text file

Tags: php, string

I use the following code to search the text file:

```
$query="red";
$FileName = "search.txt";
$fh = fopen($FileName, 'r') or die("Can't open file");
$data = fread($fh, filesize($FileName));
$Pos = strpos($data,$query);
if ($Pos)
{
    echo "Found";
}
else
{
    echo "Not Found";
}
```

Let the text file be:

```
orange_red blue_gray yellow_blue white_black
```

It finds `red` at `orange_red`,but i want to match the whole word.
For example:
If the text to be searched is to be `red`

I want it to return false because `red` does not exist independently it is part of word `orange_red`.

In brief i want to search words delimited by `space`

Searching `red` and `orange` should return false and searching `orange_red` should return true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, splits the data at a space, and then sees if the query is in the array.

```
$query="red";
$FileName = "search.txt";
$fh = fopen($FileName, 'r') or die("Can't open file");
$data = fread($fh, filesize($FileName));
$items = explode(" ", $data);
$Pos = array_search ($query, $items);
if($Pos !== FALSE)
{
    echo "Found";
}
else
{
    echo "Not Found";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the string into an array using `explode`. Then search the array using `array_search` to see if it contains your exact word.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query="red";
$FileName = "search.txt";
foreach (explode(" ", strtolower(file_get_contents($FileName)) as $word) {
    if (strtolower($query) == $word) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}
echo $found ? "Found" : "Not found";
```

Meh, a little less efficient, but it gets the job done.

Comment: Though I believe array_search is faster, I don't know.  This is another solution, non the less

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest/fastest way I can think of:

```
$query    = "red"; 
$FileName = "search.txt";

if(preg_match("/\b" . $query . "\b/i"), file_get_contents($FileName))
{
    echo "Found";
}
else
{
    echo "Not Found";
}
```

`\b` matches a word boundary, so it will only return stand-alone results for $query.  `preg_match` returns an int denoting the number of times the pattern was found (which will be either 0 or 1, as preg_match stops after the first match - use `preg_match_all` to get an accurate count of how many times the pattern appears in the target).

Answer (score -1):

Try using `strpos` with `" $query "`, or use a regular expression and [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
$query = "red";

if (strpos($data, " {$query} ") !== false) {
    // data contains " red "
}
// OR
if (preg_match("/(^{$query}( )|( ){$query}( )|( ){$query}$)/", $data) === 1) {
    // match found
}
```